# Android animation

Tags: android

When i try to make a man run in android by displaying his images with his his legs in different position the animation does not look very good.It appears as two different images switching between one another.It does not look uniform.Is there any other way to implement animation in android.

Comment: take a look about animation-drawable , and using Handler

Comment: I am using a surface view.So any animation will be in the onDraw() method.Is it possible to use the animation drawable in the onDraw() method.

Comment: i think that you can use it , i've never work with surfaceView and canvas, but i think that you can use animation drawable on it

Comment: Is there any sample code anywhere to which i can refer to.

Comment: you can do a simple search in the stackoverflow : feref this : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=animation+drawable

Comment: I could not find what i wanted.These are  different from the problem i have.

Comment: You should show the images (or similar) and your code ... then people can recreate the problem

Answer (score 0):

See, you are loading two images switching in order to show man walking. For that switching to look better as walking man, you should add alpha animation on the imageview and the animation should happen when there is image switch occuring. Hope this could improve your userInterface of "walking man"...

*create a res/anim/anim.xml animation file in your project:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="2"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</alpha>
```

*And in Activity.java file write small piece of code when you are switching:*

```
...
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.anim);
img.startAnimation(a);
....
```

And, to improve for best animation, you should use more intermediate images. 
Hope this could solve your problem.